# RestClient request returns TrustFailure error

Tags: c#, android, exception, xamarin.android, rest-client

In my xamarin.android app I am running  this to call an api.

```
var client = new RestClient(WebServicesHead.web_call + "/ping");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Session-Token", token);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

I have two devices. One android 7 and one android 4.4.4. In android 7 everything is ok, but in android 4.4.4 I am getting an error

> System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (One or more errors occurred.)

What's wrong with this? Is device or webserver error?

Comment: Are you using latest version of Mono.Android?

Comment: I am using version 8.1

Comment: I googled for the issue, seems like the issue is fixed long time ago, maybe you should try another library to make request, [Okhttp3](https://github.com/square/okhttp) if great one, here is my binding of v3 https://github.com/dehghani-mehdi/square.okhttp3

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.